# php - use array variable outside for loop

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, foreach

I have this PHP code, with a for loop:

```
        $expireData = array();
        for($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++){
            $stmt=$dbh->prepare("select round((expire - unix_timestamp()) / 86400) as days, count(*) as cnt from users WHERE user_by=:username group by days;");
            $stmt->bindParam(":username",$userdata['username']);
            $stmt->execute();

            $row = $stmt->fetchAll();

            #var_dump($row);

            if($row["cnt"] > 0){
                $expireData[]  = $row["cnt"];
            }else{
                $expireData[] = 0;
            }
        }
```

If I do the `var_dump($row)` I get:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["days"]=>
    string(2) "27"
    [0]=>
    string(2) "27"
    ["cnt"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["days"]=>
    string(3) "116"
    [0]=>
    string(3) "116"
    ["cnt"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
}
```

But if I just `echo $row['cnt'];` it doesn't echo anything out - it's empty. Why?

Ultimately, I wish to use the data from the for loop outside the for loop - like:

```
echo implode(',', $expireData);
```

But that just gives me

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that `$row` is a 2D array because you used `fetchAll()`. So `$row['cnt']` doesn't exist but `$row[0]['cnt']` does and `$row[1]['cnt']` does.

Comment: OK, maybe I'm blind, but where is the `for each`?

Comment: Sorry - for() statement. @MichaelBerkowski so how do I use it outside the for() scope?

Comment: $row[0]['cnt'].

Your $row variable is an Array with array inner.

Comment: PHP doesn't have scoping to a loop. It only has 2 basic scopes, function and global. Any variable defined in/before a loop is avaliable outside of the loop.

Comment: You know you are making the same IDENTICAL request 10 times right?

Comment: @Kypros how would you do it? This is the only thing I can think of. I am a beginner to PHP.

Comment: Follow @MichaelBerkowski answer and try to understand his logic, since that is the proper way of handling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using `fetchAll()` to retrieve all rows into `$row`, its contents are a 2 dimensional array representing *multiple* rows.  So the key `['cnt']` is present, but is one dimension farther in your array.

`$row['cnt']` doesn't exist but `$row[0]['cnt']` does and `$row[1]['cnt']` do exist.

The simplest solution with your current code is to move the `$expireData` handling outside the loop and into a loop of its own:

```
$expireData = array();

$stmt=$dbh->prepare("select round((expire - unix_timestamp()) / 86400) as days, count(*) as cnt from users WHERE user_by=:username group by days;");
$stmt->bindParam(":username",$userdata['username']);
$stmt->execute();

// Load all rows into $rows rather than $row...
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

// Loop over all rows to populate $expireData
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($row["cnt"] > 0){
        $expireData[]  = $row["cnt"];
    }else{
        $expireData[] = 0;
    }
}    
print_r($expireData);
```

The other method would be to switch from `fetchAll()` to plain `fetch()` and append rows onto `$rows` in a while loop:

```
// Array to hold all rows
$rows = array();

// (The outer for loop is removed...)    
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("select round((expire - unix_timestamp()) / 86400) as days, count(*) as cnt from users WHERE user_by=:username group by days;");
$stmt->bindParam(":username",$userdata['username']);
$stmt->execute();

// Perform single fetch() calls in a while loop
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  // Append onto array of all rows
  $rows[] = $row;

  // Then handle $expireData in the same loop
  if ($row["cnt"] > 0){
      $expireData[]  = $row["cnt"];
  }else{
      $expireData[] = 0;
  }
}
```

#### Pad the array to 10 values:

As determined in the comments, you need your final `$expireData` array to have 10 values. Rather than doing that with a loop, use [`array_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) to extend it to ten and fill it with zeros.

```
$expireData = array_pad($expireData, 10, 0);
// turns [2,8] into [2,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

#### Notes on the for loop:

The use of the outer `for` look is suspect because it is apparently executing the same statement each time. That loop may be entirely unneeded, and all you need is its body.

#### Notes on error reporting:

The fact that you did not see PHP complaining about `undefined index 'cnt'` while loading the loop suggests that you are not developing with `display_errors` turned on and `error_reporting` turned up.  *Always* do so when developing and testing code. It may have helped you see the problem sooner.

At the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Fixed that `fetchAll()` for you, hope you don’t mind.

Comment: No problem, i also think you should remove that `for` loop since this is heading for an accepted answer and could probably confuse people who read through the lines and just go for the answer in the future.

Comment: I tried using the second method, in where you removed the outer loop. Although I need to run the code 10 times - since I need 10x data to output (even if it's just a '0').

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski If you could provide the original answer with the for loop, I would be grateful. Since as said, I need it to loop through the data

Comment: @oliverbj You need 10 values in `$expireData`? The original one was executing the exact same query 10 times. How many rows does the query return?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes. If the values from the database is above 0, it should show the true value - if not, it should just show 0. I am using this data for a graph, therefore I need data for all 10 graph points.

Comment: @oliverbj But where does the number 10 come from? Your query returns 2 rows for a username. How do those relate to the 10? (the outer for loop isn't the solution - there's a different solution once I understand the problem)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski 10 is for 10 days from todays date and in the past. The "users" table is a table where users have their referrals listed, therefore I am sorting by $userdata['username'].
Yes. Exactly! The [2,8,0etc..]

Comment: It will loop through all returned rows and make the check you need as in the solution. If you have 10 different days `group by days` will return 10 rows, hence looping through 10 times as needed.

Comment: But I need it to loop x number of times (even though if there isn't x number of results in the database - as I am using it for a graph.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It should look like you posted above: [2,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Comment: @oliverbj Ok that's what I thought. No loop needed - use `array_pad()`. I'll add it above.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I really need to learn all of these functions. I'm coding multiply bottlenecks throughout the code. Thanks! Any recommendations on where to read up on PHP?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks! Although I get Array to string conversion using the array_paid

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski forgot to use the implode() function!